# How to select specific key from an array of object while creating a template using Handlerbars.js

Tags: javascript, json, templates, handlebars.js

I am trying to select a specific Key from an array of object which is like this:

```
{"test" : [{"name" : "kunal", "gender" : "male"}, {"name" : "xyz", "gender" : "male"},{"name" : "abc", "gender" : "female"}]
```

I want to select only female names from the list. How can I do that using HANDLERBARS.js. My use case doesnt fit using lodash and other libraries as I have a huge json which I am trying to templatize using handlebar.

Comment: It sounds like all that you need to do is to filter your Array. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Comment: As i said, I need to use handlerbarsjs and not a common implemented js operation on arrays

Comment: That doesn't make any sense. Handlebars is for producing HTML from a data Object, not mapping one JSON data structure into another.

Comment: Quoting from the handlebar.js docs, It uses a template and an input object to generate HTML or other text formats. I am just trying utilize the other text format to create a textified JSON.

Comment: You are using all the overhead of a templating library and a complex template to do what an Array filter and map and then a `JSON.stringify` do. (see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
"stockItems" : [
    {{#each test}}
      {{#if (test gender (toRegex "female"))}}
        {{#if @first}}{{else}},{{/if}}{
          "name" : "{{name}}",
          "value" : "{{gender}}"
        }
      {{/if}}
    {{/each}}
]
```

This worked like a charm for me :)